# QGIS display does not reflect projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have slight experience with ArcGIS, but am new to QGIS.

I'm trying to set the projection of my map, and I understand that this is done by altering the CRS (coordinate reference system) of each layer and/or the entire project.

When I right click a layer and select "Change Layer CRS", however, the visual representation of the map (the distortion) does not reflect the selected projection. My world map looks like it has a Robinson (or similar) projection, even if I select a Mercator CRS. The EPSG code in the lower right corner changes, as do the coordinates.

[image: Example image - Mercator CRS]

Setting the project CRS to the same projection does not help, nor does enabling on-the-fly projection.

My goal is to export the map to SVG, so the visual distortions are important.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please** do **not** change the CRS of the **layers**. This will make your data unusable.

Instead enable On-the-fly-projection, and change the **project** CRS to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still do not get the distortions you would expect, though. I updated my answer with an image.

Comment: OK, The NE data should be EPSG:4326, and for World Mercator use EPSG:3857.

Comment: Setting the source data (from NE) to the correct CRS did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: Apparently, the SimpleSVG plugin does not handle on-the-fly projection. Is there a way to get the same result without using on-the-fly projection? Can I reproject a layer?

Comment: Scratch that, just found 'qgis:reprojectlayer' in processing. It seems to work.