# error in overlapping layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I created two tables with PostGIS, within which I have inserted a shapefile of an Italian region (Apulia) in the first, and the coordinates in the second table.

In both tables are set with the geometry srid 4326, but by importing layers into QGIS, layers are not properly overlapped.

The procedure I followed is the following :
I downloaded the following shapefile ([link](http://www.istat.it/storage/basi-territoriali/bt_2001/R16_01.zip)), and I created the sql script with command

```
$ shp2pgsql -a -c -D -s 4326 -I R16_01 public.puglia > puglia.sql
```

within the script, the geometry is added to the table in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."puglia" ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','puglia','geom','4326','MULTIPOLYGON',2);
```

similarly, for the table coordinates

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','coord','geom','4326','POINT',2);
```

then I insert into the table coord some coordinates, also occurred via google maps ...

```
INSERT INTO mapp (gid, cod_istat, geom)
VALUES (2,3, ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint (41.8976987992015, 16.121389858102294), 4326));
```

When I import the layers in QGIS , the overlap is not what I expect . The coordinates that I post are far away from where they should be.
 
what's wrong ?

Comment: How does your polygon layer looks like? Is it well projected or is it distorted in QGIS?
Your source shape file has the `EPSG:23032`. Do you use `ogrinfo -al -so` to check your metadata?

Comment: Hi @StefanB. , my shapefile is displayed perfectly, with no distortion.  I do not know ogrinfo, but the output is this:
'PROJCS["ED_1950_UTM_Zone_32N"' quindi io dovrei convertire lo shapefile in 4326? how?

Comment: I'm currently testing your data. What is your project CRS in QGIS? The coordinate field (bottom right) shows coordinates with 7 aligned numbers running the mouse over the polygons!? Your inserted point data probably has the right UTM coordinates (xx.xxxx...). So there is the gap. The problem should be the projection of the polygon layer.

Comment: You can transform your layer CRS with `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.shp -s_srs EPSG:23032 -t_srs EPSG:4326`

Comment: @StefanB. I tried to convert the shapefile with the command `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" R16_012.shp R16_01.shp -s_srs EPSG:23032 -t_srs EPSG:4326` and then to insert it into PostGIS, but the result is still wrong in QGIS.  
The projection in QGIS is 4326

Comment: @StefanB.the overlay works much better now.
my contact details are in the "zone" right, but the distance between them is not to scale with the shapefile.
The points shown should be much closer together
my coords are:  
(41.8976987992015, 16.121389858102294)  
(41.89734482631551, 16.157066779219402)  
(41.9148504972096, 16.15738294942243)  
(41.915204686286266, 16.121696284595018)  
the coordinates should be within a distance of 3 km from each other. google map confirms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: 
I don't know if this solves the main problem, but you interchanged the longitude and latitude values in the ST_MakePoint clause.

Like the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/75688/15459) from Andre Joost.

1. Import the shapefile with the `-s 4326` and with the transformation with ogr2ogr (see comments). Create the point data table with the same EPSG (4326)
2. Find out CRS from shapefile metadata (see ogrinfo in one of the comments). Define project CRS with the `EPSG:23032` and enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation
3. Load both, the point and the polygon layer into canvas and do not change the CRS of the layers.

After that the layer should overlay correctly. The CRS units are in the given project CRS and not in degress.

Comment: Yes @Stefan B.  you, you're right.
I corrected this error, but as I said, now the "zone" is correct, but the distance between the points and the rotation of the square that form are incorrect. they are out of scale with respect to the shapefile.
I don't know why...

Comment: I'm sorry @Stefan  ... the output is correct!
Unfortunately, the shapefile is not very accurate, but the overlap works well!
problem solved!
thank you very much!